# arm sleep mode entry and exit differences WFE, WFI

Tags: arm, interrupt, cortex-m

I am reasonably new to the ARM architectures and I am trying to wrap my head around the wake up mechanism.

So first of all I am finding it difficult to find good info on this. ARM's documentation seems to be very terse on the topic.

What I'd like to understand is when the Cortex (particularly the M0 as that's what I am working with) will wake up.

For reference, I have also consulted the following:

- [What is the purpose of WFI and WFE instructions and the event signals?](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15473.html)
- [Why does the processor enter standby when using WFE instruction but not when using WFI instruction?](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15362.html)

The docs on the WFE instructions are:

```
    3.7.11. WFE
    Wait For Event.
    Syntax
    WFE
    Operation
    If the event register is 0, WFE suspends execution until 
      one of the following events occurs:
    an exception, unless masked by the exception mask registers or the current
      priority level
    an exception enters the Pending state, if SEVONPEND in the 
      System Control Register is set
    a Debug Entry request, if debug is enabled
    an event signaled by a peripheral or another processor in a 
      multiprocessor system using the SEV instruction.
    If the event register is 1, WFE clears it to 0 and completes immediately.
    For more information see Power management.
    Note
    WFE is intended for power saving only. When writing software assume 
      that WFE might behave as NOP.
    Restrictions
    There are no restrictions.
    Condition flags
    This instruction does not change the flags.
    Examples
        WFE  ; Wait for event
```

The WFI:

```
    3.7.12. WFI
    Wait for Interrupt.
    Syntax
    WFI
    Operation
    WFI suspends execution until one of the following events occurs:
    an exception
    an interrupt becomes pending, which would preempt if PRIMASK was clear
    a Debug Entry request, regardless of whether debug is enabled.
    Note
    WFI is intended for power saving only. When writing software assume 
    that WFI might behave as a NOP operation.
    Restrictions
    There are no restrictions.
    Condition flags
    This instruction does not change the flags.
    Examples
        WFI ; Wait for interrupt
```

So, some questions:

1) Firstly, can someone please clarify the difference between:

a) System Handler Priority Registers

b) Interrupt Priority Registers.
Is it just that b) are for interrupts that aren't system related such as pendSv?

Now for some scenarios. Really I would like to understand how the scenarios governed by the:
NVIC IRQ enable
NVIC pending
PRIMASK

affect the entry and exit of WFE and WFI.

So the various combinations of these bits yields 8 different scenarios
{NVIC_IRQ enable, NVIC pending, PRIMASK}.

I have already added my vague understanding so far. Please help me with this table.

- 000 - No prevention of WFE or WFI entry but no wake up condition either
- 001 - as 000
- 010 - How does pending affect entry into sleep mode for WFE and WFI?
- 011 - I guess the answer here is as 010 but with possibly different wake up conditions?
- 100 - I'd guess WFE and WFI both enter low power mode and exit low power mode no problem.
- 101 - Any difference to WFE and WFI power mode exit here?
- 110 - No idea!
- 111 - No idea!

I am excluding the priorities here as I'm not too concerned about the exception handling order just yet.

Excluding SEV and the event signals, does WFE behave the same as WFI if SEVONPEND is 0?

Comment: I can't really completely understand your question.  However, the ARM documentation is rather **vague** because it is up to the SOC implementer to hook-up these signals to different logic.  I don't think this is relevant to the NVIC (I know the GIC better) so maybe someone can answer your question directly; however, you should consult your SOC documentation to see if it has anything on this behavior.  For instance, many SOC have a register that further refines what happens on a `WFI`; *pause CPU only* to *all clocks off but DDR 32kHz self-refresh*.

Comment: For instance on some SOC, whether an interrupt will affect a `WFI` is configured through a separate register that is SOC specific.  For instance a UART module may support asynchronous static logic that will detect an incoming character.  You may configure this to wake from the deepest sleep modes.  So the *NVIC* registers might not be involved at all.  There is some internal *WFI_WAKE* type signal that the SOC will route to the core.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I wasn't aware of these extra signals. My question relates to the meanings of the aforementioned bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary mechanism for wake that you'll see on a Cortex-M is an interrupt, hence WFI (wait for interrupt).  On all of the implementations that I've seen that results in clock-gating the core, although deeper sleep/higher latency modes are sometimes available if the design supports it.

WFE is more relevant in multi-processor designs.

With regard to the questions - 
1.  Interrupts and System Handlers are very similar in the Cortex-M, differing primarily by how they are triggered.  The architecture distinguishes between them, but in practice they are the same.

Are for your bit tables, they don't really make sense.   Each Cortex-M implementation has it's own interpretation of what happens during WFI.  It can vary from basic clock gating to deep-sleep modes.  Consult your microprocessor documentation for the real story.

PRIMASK doesn't affect wake from sleep behavior.

Answer (score 2):

My answer your question about the different between WFI and WFE is based on ARM Cortex-A9 MPcore, please take a look at this link  [ARM cortex-a9 MPcore TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0388e/index.html).

Basically, there are four CPU modes run mode, standby mode, dormant mode, shutdown mode.

The differences for WFI and WFE are the way to bring CPU to run mode.

WFE can works with the execution of an SEV instruction on any processor in the multiprocessor system, and also works with an assertion of the EVENTI input signal.

WFI doesn't have these two.

Also the way they handle the causes.

WFI must work with IRQ_Handler, WFE doesn't have to.